# Extreme Slowness with Linq on mass update

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql

I wanted to do a update on potentially a million records.  I love Linq and i wrote this below to try and accomplish this. I really hope i wrote this horribly wrong.  It took Hours and hours to run.  I wrote it in T-sql and it ran in minutes.  Is there a better way to do this with linq?

```
 private static void UpdateZipCodes()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Update Zip Codes Started");
                DataDataContext _db = new DataDataContext();


                var newBadZips = (from n in _db.NewCars
                                  where n.loczip == null || n.loczip == ""
                                  select n).ToList();
                foreach (var bad in newBadZips)
                {
                    string lZip = _db.Dealers.Where(x => x.DealerID == bad.DealerID).Select(x => x.Zipcode).SingleOrDefault();

                    bad.loczip = lZip;
                    _db.SubmitChanges();


                }
                Console.WriteLine("Update Zip Codes Finshed");
            }
```

T-Sql version

```
UPDATE n

SET n.loczip = d.Zipcode

FROM            NewCars AS n INNER JOIN
                         Dealers AS d ON n.DealerID = d.DealerID
                         where n.loczip is null or n.loczip = ''
```

I understand the obvious of that linq is doing more.  I want to know how my linq query can be improved?

I am not trying to compare them in the sense i know T-sql is the right way to accomplish this. This is mainly for me become better at using linq.  I am sure i will want to do something like this on a smaller scale at one point and want to do it correctly in linq.

Comment: what do you mean by "using deletes"?

Comment: @zespri Thank you for catching that bad title.

Comment: I could be wrong, but could possibly be because you're doing 3 different actions in the code vs. the T-SQL version. You're querying the database and saving a list, then you're iterating through the list, then you're updating the database from that list. With millions of records, this is going to take quite a while.

Comment: @user2864740 i am looking for examples on how the linq can be improved

Comment: well, ef is not suited for batch update, insert, delete, whatever you want. For batch actions, use raw sql, bulk copy, but not EF and linq.

Comment: Do the join in the query itself, update records as you iterate, submit changes *once*.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Sumbitting a single batch of changes with a million records is likely to cause problems.  Better to submit in batches of a few thousand or so.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I missed the part with the size involved. New plan - submit changes *far less frequently than every record*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're querying your database for each item in a loop.  That's...bad.  It's almost always wrong, and will virtually always be very slow.

Just as you did in your T-SQL code, use a Join in your LINQ code to get all of the information you need in one query.

Next, don't update the database after each record; instead update them in batches to reduce the network traffic.  You won't be able to do a million all at once, but you can submit a batch every 100 or 1000 or whatever rows (play around with different values of a batch size to see what works best).

Also, don't call `ToList` on a table with a million records.  Just iterate the query so that the query provider can stream the data.

```
var newBadZips = (from car in _db.NewCars
                        where car.loczip == null || car.loczip == ""
                        join dealer in  _db.Dealers
                        on car.DealerID equals dealer.DealerID
                        into dealers
                        select new{
                            car,
                            zip = dealers.Select(d => d.Zipcode)
                            .SingleOrDefault(),
                        });

int count = 0;
int batchSize = 1000;
foreach(var row in newBadZips)
{
    row.car.loczip = row.zip;
    if(++count % batchSize == 0)
        _db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Note that even in this situation the LINQ code will still be far slower than simply issuing the update statement directly.

Comment: @ChrisLively Probably, yes.  But not by nearly as much, and very possibly at a level that is acceptable.

Comment: I am not trying to compare them in the sense i know T-sql is the right way to accomplish this. This is mainly for me become better at using linq.  I am sure i will want to do something like this on a smaller scale at one point and want to do it correctly in linq.

Comment: That "T-sql is the right way to accomplish this," can't be discerned from what you've given us here - you're using an ORM for a reason, and unless you've got hugely compelling time restrictions, and/or the alternative is order(s) of magnitude slower than a *correct* implementation in your ORM, using a consistent data model should win over performance gains that you aren't currently measuring.

Comment: is this right?    `on car.DealerID equals car.DealerID` i would  of thought `on car.DealerID equals Dealer.DealerID`

Comment: @jackncoke I have no idea what you're talking about.  Note that this is an off-hand, without compiler support draft to get you pointed in the right direction and may require minor tweaking based on the specifics of your query.

Comment: @Servy asking you a question about the query you wrote is what i was talking about.  in a sense of making sure what you typed was accurate because i want to learn from it.  that is all. Plus others will potentially reference this post.

Comment: @jackncoke I was making a funny; I had already edited the query within the grace period to make it appear as if I never made the mistake to begin with, and was making light of that in my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The absolute best way to increase the speed of LINQ in this situation is to simply not use LINQ.  Either run your T-SQL update query directly or throw it in a proc and call that.

Now, why would I advocate this when you obviously like LINQ?  Simple: LINQ is not providing any benefit for the use case while also being detrimental to performance.   In short, it's the wrong tool for this job.  Part of getting better at using a thing is knowing when it's inappropriate to use it.

Comment: Agreed; LINQ may read nicely, but it creates so many problems by hiding what the code is actually doing from the developer. I've seen people use reflection inside LINQ queries .... ugh!